# Docusign: Embedded sending within Basic API

Tags: api, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate our portal with Docusign so that employees could click on a link and a pop-up appears with Docusign GUI (sending window) and the system would pre-populate recipient email and name, but let the sender drag & drop fields to sign. Thus, there is no template. At the end of sending, the sender will be redirected to the internal portal.

Is this what you would call embedded sending, and will it require an Intermediate or Advanced API? This seems a minimum functionality of API, and I am hoping the Basic API could work.

Would the Basic API allow not having a template and having the sender drag and drop fields for each envelope to send?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would work, this is a simple scenario.
To get started I would check out this [code example](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-sending) we have on the developer center.
It includes code snippets in 8 languages and links to GitHub where we have the full source code using the different SDKs. 
You will need to learn how to use authentication so you can access the API, all of that is documented there as well.

Comment: Thanks! I checked that page and the API Explorer. To reiterate my query: Is what we are trying to accomplish (embedded sending) allowed in Basic API?

Also, what's the difference between embedded sending (what you shared) and embedding the console (https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedding-console)? Are any of these allowed in Basic API?

Comment: Yes, it is allowed in Basic API, sorry I wasn't clear.